# Open external links in new tab but exclude certain links

Tags: jquery

I found the following code from somewhere which suppose to open external links in new tab and it's working fine.

The problem I'm facing now, the "scroll to top" button also opens new tab and loads a blank page. The scroll to top button doesn't have href but has an ID. How can I exclude the element ID in the code?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('a').each(function() {
        var a = new RegExp('/' + window.location.host + '/');
        if(!a.test(this.href)) {
            $(this).click(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                event.stopPropagation();
                window.open(this.href, '_blank');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You could use `:not` (see jQuery selectors documentation). Or you could give the external links a specific class and change this code to only select that class instead of all `a` elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `not` selector ( If the id of link is `top_link_id`)

```
$("a:not(#top_link_id)").each...
```

Or

```
   $("a").not("top_link_id").each...
```

Comment: Thanks very much! I didn't think of it that way! Here's my final code that solves the problem:

    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 $("a:not(#ast-scroll-top)").each(function() {
  var a = new RegExp('/' + window.location.host + '/');
  if(!a.test(this.href)) {
   $(this).click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    window.open(this.href, '_blank');
   });
  }
 });
    });

Comment: Sorry, I had no idea how to format code in the comment.